# Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a_n := (-1)^n(1-\frac{1}{n})$. Find Limit Superior and Inferior. Does it converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$a_n := (-1)^n\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)$$

a) Find Limit Superior and Inferior of $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$

b) Does it converge ?

---

I'm a bit confused how to prove that formally. The limit inferior seems to be $-1$ and superior $1$, but how do I prove that formally ? Do I need somehow to use $\epsilon$ notation ?

For b), it does not seem to converge.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n\bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg) = \lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n-\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n - 0 = \lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n$$ Is this proof for b) formal enough ?

Comment: Note that $-1\leq a_n\leq 1$ for all $n$. Now, consider $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n+1}\}$. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Random $a_{2n} = 1 - 1/n$ and $a_{2n+1} = 1/n - 1$ So this means $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} = 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1} = -1$. But do I need to somehow formally prove that $-1 \leq a_n \leq 1$ ?

Comment: @wengen Yes, you would need that, but that's really not difficult. Try to prove $|a_n|\leq 1$

Comment: @wengen, yes you need to prove it for completeness. Actually, for any sequence $\{a_n\}$, if there exists a non-negative number $M$ such that $|a_n|\leq M$ for all $n$, then $-M\leq \liminf a_n\leq \limsup a_n \leq M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that, for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$\sup_{k\geq n}(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1$$

and

$$\inf_{k\geq n}(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=-1.$$

This can easily be seen as we can disregard the negative terms when considering the $\sup$ as we always have positive terms (meaning the upper bounds for the sequence with only positive terms are the same as the upper bounds for the sequence), and the positive terms form an increasing sequence, so the $\sup$ is the limit as $k\to\infty$, and a similar argument gives you the $\inf$. Consequently

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1$$

and

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\geq n}(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=-1.$$

As for (b), recall that the limit exists if any only if the limit superior and limit inferior coincide. As they do not, the limit does not exist.